# Got promoted which is verb here?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> They got promoted.

Which word is a verb here, between got & promoted, and why?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "**They got promoted**" uses a **passive-voice form of the verb "promote" in the past tense**. In formal/academic writing, the passive voice of a given verb (such as "see," "tell," or "promote") is often constructed as follows:
(1) **a conjugated form of the verb "to be" as a helping verb (i.e., auxiliary verb)**, followed by
(2) **the past participle of the verb** that's being expressed in the passive voice.  (The past participle is the form of a verb that is used after the helping verb when forming the perfect tenses, such as the present perfect tense.  Examples of past participles include "seen" (as in "I have seen this before"), "told" (as in "She hasn't told them yet") or "promoted" (as in "The publisher had promoted the book enthusiastically up until that point").

For example, if we start with the **active voice** sentence "The guard **saw** the thieves," the verb is **saw**, which is the past tense form of the verb **see**. The **passive voice** version of this sentence would be "The thieves **were seen** by the guard." In this case, *were* (which is a form of the verb *be*)  is the helping verb, and *seen* is the past particle of the verb *see*.

In informal usage, the helping/auxiliary verb "get" is often used instead of the verb "be."  For example, "The cheaters **were** caught" may be expressed as "The cheaters **got** caught."  Similarly, "He **is** bullied by the other kids" may be expressed as "He **gets** bullied by the other kids," and "The winners **will be** chosen randomly" may be expressed as "The winners **will get** chosen randomly."

Let's dissect your sentence, "They got promoted."  The subject of the verb is *They*. The verb is *got promoted*, which is a passive-voice, past-tense form of the verb *promote*. This passive-voice verb form is constructed using the two components mentioned earlier: (1) A helping/auxiliary verb, which in this case is *got* (although a form of *be* may also be used), followed by (2) the past participle of the verb *promote*, which is *promoted*.

In a more formal context, this sentence could be written as "They were promoted," where the helping verb *were* (which is a conjugated form of the verb *be*) is used instead of a form of the verb *get*.